# Net use \\localhost\c$ - command fail with error 1231

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

on my windows 7 x64 , i'm trying to execute this command :

**net use \\localhost\c$**

But the command fail with the error 1231, Network location cannot be reached.
I've tried to re create again the admin share c$ (c:) , but it's the same situation.
On another Windows 7 machine , this command is completed successfully.
What can i do ?
Thank you !

Comment: you're missing a backslash on localhost. it should be \\localhost ... have you tried 127.0.0.1 instead? Why are you mapping a local drive for a local resource?

Comment: Can you see `C$` administrative share in `net view localhost /all`?  `net view 127.0.0.1 /all`?  `net view %COMPUTERNAME% /all`? `net share`?

Answer (score 1):

#### The command fail with the error 1231, Network location cannot be reached

```
net use \localhost\c$
```

The above command is invalid as the syntax is incorrect.

1. You are missing a `device` name.
2. `computername` (in this case `localhost`) should start with two backslashes `\\` (this is the actual cause of the error).

> On another Windows 7 machine , this command is completed successfully.

That is not possible as it is an invalid command.

Try the following command (replace the drive letter as appropriate):

```
net use j: \\localhost\c$
```

You could also use:

```
net use \\localhost\c$
```

but this seems a pointless command as this is creating a remote reference (to a local resource) that has no local reference (`device name`) that can actually refer to it.

**Example:**

```
F:\test>net use j: \\localhost\c$
The command completed successfully.


F:\test>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           J:        \\localhost\c$            Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.

F:\test>net use \\localhost\c$
The command completed successfully.


F:\test>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\localhost\c$            Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

---

#### Syntax

```
F:\test>net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) - Map a drive letter to a remote server/share.

Comment: How to make to any %username% ?

Comment: @Kangarooo I don't understand your comment.